# How to say "leave a gap"?

Tags: word-choice, translation

As in instructions for making something. Like "leave a gap on the left side" or "leave gaps on both sides" 
「左側に間をする」 
「両側に間をする」 
I'm guessing this is like "do a space" which makes no sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb you need is [空【あ】ける](http://jisho.org/search/%E9%96%93%E3%82%92%E7%A9%BA%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B).

> - 左側に間を空ける
> - 両側に間を空ける

間をする makes no sense.

Comment: There is a semantic difference between "make/open a gap"  (new gap that wasn't there before) and "leave a gap" (preserve one that already exists) in English.  Are both cases 空ける in Japanese?

Comment: I see two readings for 左側 in dictionaries, which is more likely to be used?

Comment: Wouldn't the kanji 開 be more appropriate instead of 空? They both read the same though.

Comment: 「間を空けておく」 may be more appropriate depending on the context, but 「間を残す」 is not really common. さそく/うそく/りょうそく are rare and only appear in technical jargon. In general, 空 is making something empty/vacant (vs filled/occupied/満), while 開 is making something open (vs closed/閉). I believe 空ける is better here, but they are sometimes used interchangeably.

Comment: @WeirdlyCheezy 空ける doesn't describe anything else than a gap is left afterwards. If you want to tell explicitly "preserve", maybe you can say 空けた（空いた）ままにする.

Answer (score 1):

Also see the terms 余白 and しろ (ex. 縫いしろ). I'm not sure what your exact use case is, but 間 seems more commonly used to describe spatial or temporal gaps between things or events.